# displaying data from MySQL in Datalist problems

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a `<datalist>` element that gets a list of names from a table in a MySQL database. The list suggests names when you start typing, however there are some double Barrelled names in the Database, which it does not list.

Here is the code, showing the while loop etc.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM students";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<input id="ChildName" name="ChildName" list="names" style=" width:450px; height:45px;font-size:20pt;" maxlength="15" size="6" > <datalist id="names">';
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows[Name]; ?>">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: What is in `$result` and where is your query?

Comment: @Daan I missed that bit out when I copied the code. Have added it to my original code above!

Comment: Just guessing - <option value='"<?php echo $rows[Name]; ?>"'>

Comment: what is the problem in your code?

Comment: It displays the names in the table 'Students', but does not display them if they are double barrelled i.e. Jordan-James Smith

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code to see what is actually being outputted?

Comment: I have tried that. For normal names they are displayed properly, but then for the double barrelled names nothing is output at all.

Comment: Okay, So i have been doing a bit more digging and have found now that If I 'echo $rows[Name];' then it does display all the names correctly. I have also found that it is not just double barrelled names, but it seems to be names over a certain length?

Answer (score 1):

I am a Network / System Administrator but I have write code while selecting my own available Database, Please change columns accordingly, here is the solution and hope this will work for you as well

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = '';
$dbName = 'rizwanranjha';

$dbConn = mysqli_connect ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ('mysqli connect failed. ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($dbConn, $dbName) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysqli_error());

$sql = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT * FROM iph_country");

echo '<input id="ChildName" name="ChildName" list="names" style=" width:450px; height:45px;font-size:20pt;" maxlength="15" size="6" >';
echo '<datalist id="names">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<option value='". $row['country_id']. "'>" . $row['country_name'] ."</option>";
    }
echo '</datalist>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM students"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo '<input id="ChildName" name="ChildName" list="names" style=" width:450px; height:45px;font-size:20pt;" maxlength="15" size="6" > <datalist    id="names">';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows["Name"]; ?>">
<?php
}
?>
</datalist>
```

either you use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and then use $row['columnname']
OR
you use mysql_fetch_array($result) and then use $row[1];